# How to format LINQ query for Dynamics 365 c# plugin

Tags: c#, linq, plugins, microsoft-dynamics

I am looking to create a c# plugin that runs when a field is updated. I am a little confused on how to format a LINQ query to interact with dynamics

I have a Dynamics entity called `bname_jobs` which I need to query.

looking at some code currently sitting within the business the LINQ starts off with

```
var processlineitems = from processLineItem in xrm.bname_processlineitemSet
```

My question is how do I find out the names of the entity I want to query in the above format

I need to fill in the x's in the below code

```
var jobs = from xxxx in xrm.bname_xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The "set" objects are cached sets of data generally used by client applications. You should not use these when querying within a plugin. Read up on the QueryExpression object as Ank suggests.

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Comment: Yep, the "from" section I could put anything I wanted in, and we have a class file which maps out all of the entities within dynamics, this just needed regenerating to include the new entity and that is what goes in the "in" section

Answer (score 1):

To query a Dynamics 365 Entity ther are various ways.

1. [Query Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/build-queries-with-queryexpression)
2. [Fetchxml Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-fetchxml-construct-query)

When writing code in c# in most of the case, I have seen developers go with query expression.

Few examples with query expression and d365

[Example 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/samples/retrieve-multiple-queryexpression-class)

[Example 2](https://carldesouza.com/dynamics-crm-retrieve-multiple-query-expression/)

Now how to find Entity name, in your context you are looking for entity schema name.

Go to CRM (UI)--> Advanced Settings--> Settings-->Customization-->Cutomize the system( It will open default solution)--> Entites on left hand side--> select your entity.

Images below will show you how to direct

[image]

[image]

In this case my Entity display name is "Case" but it's schema name is "incident".

This is what you need to query in your querexpression or fetchxml

[image]